# Strange "et cetera" chat glitch?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, autocomplete

Us over at RPG.SE were having a fun discussion about [punching people who came up with &c.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10654809#10654809) as an abbreviation for et cetera.

I decided to make a couple ridiculous jokes. The first one was, `@{}Ra`, which was nothing spectacular.

The second one caused a small glitch. I proposed `@{}||a` as an alternative to "&c.," and to my surprise, this came up:

[image: lists]

Apparently, typing `@|` causes the chat box to ignore the special symbols thereafter, and allow you to enter any name. The ping does not actually go through, though. This is small, since pressing tab removes the special symbols, but still worth noting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were letting some characters (the `|` bar in particular) through unescaped when building a regular expression to search for the typed-in user name in all present users.

I briefly considered just allowing *all* regex characters for the autocompleter ("Who was that guy again with two *x* in the name and a number followed by one to three apostrophes?"), but then decided against it :)

Fixed now.

Comment: Easy fix. 3 XP awarded, and two silver pieces for your time! Thank you!